# Can the view orientation switched from portrait to landscape and vice versa in Adobe Acrobat Reader?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

On my tablet, Adobe Acrobat Reader goes into portrait mode for a document with portrait proportions. I tried to find a way to switch it to landscape mode, but I'm still clueless.

Can the view orientation switched from portrait to landscape and vice versa in Adobe Acrobat Reader?

Or is this very basic feature in fact *really* missing?

Comment: I don't know about Adobe but you can use automation (Automate App) to automatically lock your device into landscape orientation as soon as Adobe is opened and switch back to normal when closed. If it helps